# How to redraw a pyplot multiple times for different axis parameters

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using IPython Notebook. I have a bunch of plots in the same figure. 
I need to show these plots using different axis parameters, i.e, for the following four cases:

```
Cases  x-axis   y-axis
1      non-log  non-log
2      non-log  log
3      log      non-log
4      log      log
```

Is there an easy way like this:

```
#many lines of code for generating bunch of plots
plt.show()

#figure shown with non-log axis

ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()

#figure shown with log y-axis    

ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.show()

#figure shown with log x-axis and log y-axis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.show()` will show figure(s) and discart them afterwards. It's not intended to be used several times in a script.

An option you have would be to do your plotting in a function and depending on the arguments, create a different figure. The following will create figures for all 4 cases:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(0,3, 250)
y = .4*x

def plot(x,y,logx=False, logy=False):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    if logy: ax.set_yscale('log')
    if logx: ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.plot(x,y)


plot(x,y)
plot(x,y, True, False)
plot(x,y, False, True)
plot(x,y, True, True)

plt.show()
```